# Como criptografar StringConnection para um banco remoto MySql em C#

Tags: c#, mysql, sql, banco-de-dados

Estou desenvolvendo uma aplicação que pretendo vender, e por isso criei um sistema de verificação de serial, que verifica se aquele código de ativação já está associado ao MAC do PC. Eu faço isso me conectando a um banco de dados remoto. **Se alguém tiver uma ideia melhor e mais fácil de como posso criar esse tipo de serial de ativação, estou aceitando sugestões hehehe**

Minha dúvida é, como eu faço pra proteger as informações de login dispostas da String de Conexão.

Tenho lá

```
connString "SERVER=xxx;PORT=3306;DATABASE=xxx;UID=xxx;PASSWORD=**xxx**;";
```

Acredito que deixa isso disposto no código permita que possam roubar os dados de acesso ao meu banco de dados. Há alguma maneira de criptografar isso? Ou teria que fazer isso direto no servidor do banco.

Answer (score 1):

Se a `ConnectionString` estiver armazenada no `app.config` pode sempre seguir este tutorial bastante detalhado no *CodeProject*: https://www.codeproject.com/Articles/15392/Implementing-Protected-Configuration-With-Windows

Se apenas pretende encriptar/decriptar uma `string`, da mesma forma que faria com uma *password*, existe a possibilidade de utilizar uma encriptação AES: https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.security.cryptography.aes(v=vs.110).aspx